# Python: Using a dynamically loaded module fails with AttributeError

Tags: python, tkinter, virtualenv, python-import

**Environment**:

- Python: 3.9
- Virtualenv under PyCharm

In the current source code I'm writing I try to:

1. Dynamically check if the required dependencies are installed
2. If not, a message appears and the program stops, otherwise, go to 3
3. The source code dynamically imports the installed module
4. The code uses the module as usual when it is required

The thing is that the code is failing at (4) with the **tkfilebrowser** module. This is my code for importing:

```
already_imported = {}

def do_import(dependency):
    """
    Imports the dependency module

    :param dependency: the name of the dependency module to import
    :raise: ModuleNotFoundError if not found
    :return: the imported module
    """
    global already_imported
    if dependency in already_imported:
        result_module = already_imported[dependency]
    else:
        result_module = importlib.import_module(dependency)
        already_imported[dependency] = result_module

    return result_module
```

Just after the call, this is the context:

```
>>> tkfilebrowser = do_import('tkfilebrowser')
>>> dir(tkfilebrowser)
['__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']

>>> type(tkfilebrowser)
<class 'module'>

>>> print(tkfilebrowser)
<module 'tkfilebrowser' (namespace)>

>>> tkfilebrowser.askopendirname()
AttributeError: module 'tkfilebrowser' has no attribute 'askopendirname'
```

I couldn't guess what's wrong here and what I should be doing for using the module correctly.

Comment: So what is `tkfilebrowser`? It seems to be a valid variable, its just that it doesn't have the attribute you are looking for.

Comment: i cannot duplicate the above error, so make sure the module is installed correctly on your device, maybe remove and reinstall it, also your function has no purpose since python import statement only executes once, even when called for the same module from multiple places, all import statements of the same module will share the same object, your implementation is only slower than python "import" statement, and it makes it harder for external packages to detect your use of external modules.

Comment: _"I can't guess what's wrong"_ - don't guess. Do some debugging. What is the output of `print(tkfilebrowser)` immediately before calling `tkfilebrowser.askopendirname()`? Does `dir(tkfilebrowser)` list `askopendirname` as an attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything was working in the source code.

The problem was that I was using an incorrect Python binary in the Run configuration of PyCharm so, as soon as I realized, I changed it and all come along well.

So if anyone comes here with a similar error, just make really sure that your virtualenv or whatever is the Python environment you have configured is really being used and not another one.

In PyCharm:

Edit configurations => Python interpreter